# split Dataset to N size datesets by Date?

Tags: r

Seems like a trivial question but I couldn't find the answer online.

I have a dataset of 1259 observation by 7 variables.
One of the variables is Date and I want to split the dataset to small datasets of size 50*7 that will keep in order the dates.

I've tried to to this and got the right size of dataset but the dates were messed up.

```
split(data, sample(1:50), nrow(data),replace = T)
```

Comment: In what universe 1259 is a large data set? :) In eitherway, a simple way could be `res <- split(data, seq_len(nrow(data)) %/% 50)`. Though the first group will have 49 rows (you''ll need to add a small fix if this is important) and the last group will have only 10 (due to remainder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `Date` column in the data of "Date" class, you can `order` the `data` based on it and use `cut` to `split` data into 7 groups.

```
data <- data[order(data$Date), ]
list_data <- split(data, cut(seq_len(nrow(data)), 7))
```

This will return a list of dataframes which can be accessed using `list_data[[1]]`, `list_data[[2]]` etc.